# MSSQL/Codeignitre active record query returning no records

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm trying simple SQL query (MSSQL database - driver sqlsrv) using codeigniter active record, which is working as it should on my localhost but not on my godaddy setup!

even weird is if I run count_all_records it returns exact count of rows but when I try to get 'TOP 100' records it returns an empty array.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM basic
```

returns number of rows in TABLE 'basic' but

```
SELECT  TOP 100 * FROM basic ORDER BY SSN
```

returns an empty array (all this works just fine in localhost - same config)

Active record query to count rows:

```
$this->db->from("basic");
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Active record query to get TOP 100 rows:

```
$limit = 100; $start = 0;
$sidx = 'SSN'; $sord = 'asc';

$this->db->from("basic");
$result = $this->db->order_by($sidx, $sord)->limit($limit, $start)->get()->result_array();
```

I have checked config, the login/signup is working fine on app I'm working but this specific query (on multiple tables) fail to return any data!

It is returning an empty CI_DB_sqlsrv_result Object for some reason

```
CI_DB_sqlsrv_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => Resource id #2
    [result_id] => Resource id #8
    [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_row] => 0
    [num_rows] => 100
    [row_data] => 
)
```

Any ideas what I maybe doing wrong!

Comment: ok I found the solution, though it wasn't really anything to do with programming, like I mentioned it worked flawlessly on my localhost and I also tried the same in another windows server online, godaddy guys told me the tables are simply too big and query was taking more time (even if I pull 10-20 rows!) and they can not help, so I switched my code to rackspace and there you go, everything working as it should!

So if you have similar problem and you are using godaddy, find another server, it's not your code which is giving you creeps, it's godaddy!!

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('basic');
$this->db->order_by($sidx, $sord); 
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Or You can use Method Chaining Like shown below.

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('basic')->order_by($sidx, $sord)->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I think issue is with your Method chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix function _limit() in sqlsrv_driver.php for using limit, start as in mysql.
Please read http://ahmad-firuze.blogspot.com/2013/05/codeigniter-sqlsrvdriverphp-function.html